# R geom density ridges- simultaneously adding lines for mean and median

Tags: r

I'm currently working on producing a few geom density plots in R. I need to plot lines in each ridge for median and mean. I have found code to do one or the other (mean or median), but for some reason can't get my code to function to produce both.

code to produce lines for the mean :

```
ggplot(data_table, aes_(as.name(xvar), as.name(yvar))) + geom_density_ridges(quantile_lines=TRUE, quantile_fun=function(x,...)mean(x)) + ggtitle(paste0(title)) + xlab(paste0(xlabel)) + ylab(paste0(ylabel)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, face="plain", angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1))
```

[image]

code to produce lines for the median :

```
ggplot(data_table, aes_(as.name(xvar), as.name(yvar))) + geom_density_ridges(quantile_lines=TRUE, quantiles=2) + ggtitle(paste0(title)) + xlab(paste0(xlabel)) + ylab(paste0(ylabel)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, face="plain", angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1))
```

[image]

When I try to combined these two methods, I don't get two lines. How can I write the code above to achieve a geom_density_ridges output containing lines for both the median and mean simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else- I found a way to add both mean and median to the function statement and was able to produce plots with both lines simultaneously.

```
mean_median <- function(x, ...) {
  mean <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  median <- median(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  c(median, mean)
}

ggplot(data_table, aes_(as.name(xvar), as.name(yvar))) + geom_density_ridges(quantile_lines=TRUE, quantile_fun=function(x,...)mean_median(x)) + ggtitle(paste0(title)) + xlab(paste0(xlabel)) + ylab(paste0(ylabel)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, face="plain", angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1))
```